# PSYoungGen Pause Jitter

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm

I am observing some strange behaviors in my java application. Minor GC pause times are very stable, between 2 to 4 milliseconds, and spaced several seconds apart (ranging from around 4 seconds to minutes depending on busyness). I have noticed that before the **first** full GC, minor collection pause times can spike to several hundred milliseconds, sometimes breaching the seconds mark. However, after the first full collection, these spikes go away and minor collection pause times do not spike anymore and remain rock steady between 2-4 milliseconds. These spikes do not appear to correlate with tenured heap usage.

I'm not sure how to diagnose the issue. Obviously something changed from the full collection, or else the spikes would continue to happen. I'm looking for some ideas on how to resolve it.

Some details:

- I am using the -server flag. The throughput parallel collector is used.
- Heap size is at 1.5G, default ratio is used between young and tenured generation. Survivor rations remain at default. I'm not sure how relevant these are to this investigation as the same behavior is shown despite more tweaking.
- On startup, I make several DB calls. Most of the information can be GC'd away (and does upon a full collection). Some instances of my application will GC while others will not.

What I've tried/thought about:

- Full Perm Gen? I think the parallel collector handles this fine and does not need more flags, unlike CMS.
- Manually triggering a full GC after startup. I will be trying this, hopefully making the problem go away based on observations. However, this is only a temporary solution as I still don't understand why there is even an issue.

Answer (score 0):

First, wanted more information on this but since comment needs 50 repo which I dont have so asking here.
This is too less info to work with.

To diagnose the issue you can switch on the GC logs and post the behaviour that you notice. Also, you can use jstat to view the heap space usage live while application is running: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/share/jstat.html

To turn on GC logs you can read here : http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/gc-tuning-6-140523.html